# I am trying to populate an array with mysql rows but the array is always empty

Tags: node.js

Attached is a node.js route for displaying product data for the product ids that a user enters in an html form. In this route, I have the array 'prod_id_arr' with product ids. For each prod_id in this array, I select  the mysql product database row and add it to another array 'data'. I then use the 'data' array to display the product data in "prod_multi_upd_pg" view at the end. The prod_id_arr array seems fine when I console.log it. Also, I console.log the 'data' array after adding each row and it looks fine. But, when I console log the 'data' array at the end after all rows are added, it is shown as empty. This should be straight forward but I can't get it to work.

My understanding from answers to similar questions at stackoverflow is  that this is due to the async nature of js where queries always complete after the console.log and that is why the console.log shows the data array as empty. I also know that I should be using promise or aync/await to handle this situation. I have tried both in a js 'for' loop but had no success probably because I didn't do it right. So I went back to this basic code where I add each row to the data array manually but the problem remains.

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
// Route to display current data for multiple product updates. 
app.get('/prod_multi_upd_pg', (req, res) => {
    let prod_id_arr = req.query.prod_id_arr.split(','); 
    data = new Array(8); 
    if (prod_id_arr[0]) {
        prod_id = prod_id_arr[0];
        con.query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_id = ?', [prod_id], function(err, row) {
            if (row.length == 0) {
                alert("Ürün kodu bulunamadı, lütfen geçerli bir ürün kodu girin.");
                return;
            } else {
                data[0] = row;
            }   
        })
    }
    if (prod_id_arr[1]) {
        prod_id = prod_id_arr[1];
        con.query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_id = ?', [prod_id], function(err, row) {
            if (row.length == 0) {
                alert("Ürün kodu bulunamadı, lütfen geçerli bir ürün kodu girin.");
                return;
            } else {
                data[1] = row;
            }   
        })
    }           
    if (prod_id_arr[2]) {
        prod_id = prod_id_arr[2];
        con.query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_id = ?', [prod_id], function(err, row) {
            if (row.length == 0) {
                alert("Ürün kodu bulunamadı, lütfen geçerli bir ürün kodu girin.");
                return;
            } else {
                data[2] = row;
            }   
        })
    }
    console.log("data: ", data);
    res.render("prod_multi_upd_pg", {data});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the asynchronous of js and you handle this by using await and here is an altarnative approche.

```
app.get('/prod_multi_upd_pg', async (req, res) => {
    let prod_id_arr = req.query.prod_id_arr.split(',');
    let data = new Array(8);
    const getProductData = async (prod_id, index) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            con.query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_id = ?', [prod_id], (err, row) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve({ index, row });
                }
            });
        });
    };

    try {
        const promises = prod_id_arr.map(async (prod_id, index) => {
            if (prod_id) {
                const { index: dataIndex, row } = await getProductData(prod_id, index);
                if (row.length === 0) {
                    throw new Error("Ürün kodu bulunamadı, lütfen geçerli bir ürün kodu girin.");
                }
                data[dataIndex] = row;
            }
        });

        // Mark as async
        await Promise.all(promises.map(async fn => await fn()));

        console.log("data: ", data);
        res.render("prod_multi_upd_pg", { data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error.message);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: BugHunter, thanks for your help. I ran your code but I get 'SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules' error.

Comment: Sorry for a late responnse I have updated my code and it should work now

Comment: BugHunter, thanks for your help but I already resolved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dynamic version of your code. Using map and promise all is better than for loop that's why I used them.

```
app.get('/prod_multi_upd_pg', async (req, res) => {
    const prod_id_arr = req.query.prod_id_arr.split(',');

    const fetchData = async (prod_id) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            con.query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_id = ?', [prod_id], (err, row) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(row.length === 0 ? null : row);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    try {
        const dataPromises = prod_id_arr.map((prod_id, index) => fetchData(prod_id));

        const data = await Promise.all(dataPromises);

        console.log("data: ", data);
        // You can also check here null status of data then notify with an alert.
        res.render("prod_multi_upd_pg", { data });
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Ürün kodu bulunamadı, lütfen geçerli bir ürün kodu girin.");
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried both BugHunter's and furkanansn's code. They both give 'SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules' error on the line 'await Promise.all(dataPromises);'.  When I remove the await keyword from this line, the syntax  error is gone but then it hits the 'Internal server error' section. Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: furkanansn, I didn't copy your code correctly, I corrected the code and now I get the data array coming out right.  However, it doesn't display the product data on the next page but it is a different problem that I have to look into. Thanks for your help.